# upload files from kaggle to google drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api, kaggle, pydrive

I am using kaggle to train a model and once training is done I would like upload the trained model to google drive as I cant figure out a way to download the model locally. I looked into using https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/ after doing pip install pydrive I tried authenticating

```
    import os
    from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
    from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
    from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
```

then

```
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

I get this error 
ApplicationDefaultCredentialsError: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.

Is there another way to do this?

Also I have not commited my files in kaggle as I stop the training manually so the commit would go on forever and i get a more than 6 subdirectories error after I tried commiting and stopping a commit in the output area

Answer (score 8):

I was facing the same problem and was able download files from `Kaggle` to `Colab` then move to `Google Drive`. For example, if the current directory is `/kaggle/working` and the file to move is `processed_file.zip` then,

### From Kaggle

```
from IPython.display import FileLink
FileLink(r'processed_file.zip')
```

This will generate a link,

```
https://....kaggle.net/...../processed_file.zip
```

### From Colab

```
!wget "https://....kaggle.net/...../processed_file.zip"
```

### Mount Google Drive

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

### Copy File to Google Drive

```
!cp "/content/processed_file.zip" "/content/drive/My Drive/workspace"
```

Comment: its not working anymore. kaggle throws 404 for the file

Comment: Yes, it not working and throws 404 error for the file. Also link generated through the code  do not include complete path but from current working directory.

Comment: Nice one man, it works

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do the same: to save my kaggle model to google drive.

When you call `gauth.Authorize()`, the gauth object is looking for a valid `gauth.credentials`.

Instead of using `gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()`, I'm using:

```
# Try to load saved client credentials
gauth = GoogleAuth()
credential_file = 'gdrive.json'
gauth.LoadCredentialsFile(credential_file)
```

The credential file is created at your local computer by:

```
gauth = GoogleAuth()
credential_file = 'gdrive.json'
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
gauth.SaveCredentialsFile(credential_file)
```

After getting the the credential file, upload it to kaggle then you can use it in your session.

The credential will expire but I tried my kaggle session after 8 hours and it's still working.

Checking the expire time using:

```
gauth.credentials.token_expiry
```