# how to move files from kaggle to google drive usig google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, kaggle

In google_colab i have imported files from kaggle using kaggle token

```
# File Uplod
from google.colab import files;
files.upload()

!mkdir -p ~/.kaggle
!cp kaggle.json ~/.kaggle/
!chmod 600 ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json
!kaggle competitions download -c quora-question-pairs
```

Is there a possibility to move imported files (from kaggle) to google drive permenantly.

Answer (score 1):

I have answered a similar question here,
[upload files from kaggle to google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55149143/upload-files-from-kaggle-to-google-drive/64462301#64462301).

Using code below to generate download link in `Kaggle` and using `wget` in `Colab` I was able get the file in colab. From there it can copied to drive using python or shell command.

```
from IPython.display import FileLink
FileLink(r'processed_file.zip')
```

Answer (score 0):

Mount your Google Drive as a filesystem using this code snippet:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Details: 
https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=u22w3BFiOveA

Then, you can copy whatever files you wish from your backend into your Drive at `/content/drive`.