# Download Kaggle output file

Tags: kaggle

I created a file in Kaggle with Python. It is in the path `/kaggle/working/`. If I click on the three dots and want to click download, it doesn't happen. I've tried several different browsers.
Does anyone have a solution?

---

**Edit**

I found that code snippet. Unfortunately it does not work. I have an h5 file that I would like to download it.

```
!tar -zcvf outputname.tar.gz /kaggle/working
```

Answer (score 2):

This does somewhat similar task, [upload files from kaggle to google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55149143/upload-files-from-kaggle-to-google-drive/64462301#64462301).

You can use below snippet to generate a file download link for `h5`, `zip`, `tar.gz` and more, then download using `wget`, browser, download manager etc.

The download link will be shown in output of the cell. You may need to enable internet in kaggle notebook settings (should still work when disabled).

```
from IPython.display import FileLink
FileLink(r'outputname.tar.gz')
```

```
from IPython.display import FileLink
FileLink(r'outputname.h5')
```

Comment: That displays page not found. EDIT: no it works, note that "/kaggle/working/" path part should be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

The base directory is /kaggle/working.
If you want to download file /kaggle/working/a/b/c.tgz, follow steps.

```
%cd /kaggle/working
from IPython.display import FileLink
FileLink('a/b/c.tgz')
```

Answer (score 0):

The code looks good to me. Instead of the 3dots, try going to the right-hand column and choosing "Output". You should see your file there.